# How to capture console error logs using selenium4 ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

We are trying to capture the console log error's which is throw from front end errors. Below code snippet used for capture the logs,

```
$driver.on_log_event(:console) do |event|
        $logs.push(event)
    end
```

By this code snippet we could capture only the browser default and not capturing the application thrown errors. Are we missing anything here.

This error's are captured from console,
[image]

The below actual errors are not capturing on the logs,

[image]

I could able to capture console error's using selenium4 method "on_log_event" method. But need to capture the network api error as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.